# Problem : Creation of a button on a calculator in HTML/CSS (Design only)

Tags: html, css

I am building a calculator on HTML/CSS. I have some buttons. Two of them are slightly different- I only want to change the color of those 2 buttons (into blue). 
But I am a beginner in HTML and I don`t want to duplicate my code. 
So I asking you:
How do I create those two buttons which are similar to any other button, with different background color instead only?

My calculator is: https://pasteboard.co/I8iFbTB.jpg .

For example, in OOP I create a class of button (father) and a son who heritage it. The only difference between them is that the son has one more line in its code: a background color. 
No need to do copy-paste (exactly what I want to do in HTML),
"Dbutton" will inherit "button" (there is an HTML code here).
I wrote a code that works. I just need to get rid of some lines on Dbutton.

Any help will be appreciated!

Haim

My code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Lab 1 example</title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<style>

    body {
        font-family: Verdana, Ariel;
        margin: 140px;
    }
    p1 {
        color: white;
        font-size: 30px;
        position: relative;
        left: 15px;
        top: 00px;
        padding-left: 2%;
        margin-top: 1%;
    }

    p2 {
        color: black;
        font-size: 30px;
        padding-right: 1%;
        padding-bottom: 2%;
        position: relative;
        top: 60px;
    }


    #monitor {
        background-color: lightgreen;
        color: black;
        font-size: 30px;
        border: 3px solid red;
        width: 90%;
        height: 20%;
        padding-right: 3%;
        margin: auto;
        position: relative;
        left: 01px;
        top: 10px;
        text-align: right;

    }

    .button {
        float: left;
        width: 12%;
        height: 8%;
        border: 2px solid silver;
        cursor: pointer;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 10px;
        color: white;
        padding-left: 5%;
        position: relative;
        left: 35px;
        top: 30px;
    }

    .Dbutton {      //$=this is duplication (I don`t need it)
        float: left;  //$
        width: 12%;   //$ 
        height: 8%;   //$
        border: 2px solid silver;   //$
        cursor: pointer;   //$
        text-align: center;  //$
        padding: 10px;   //$
        color: white;   //$
        padding-left: 5%;   //$
        position: relative;   //$
        left: 35px;  //$
        top: 30px;  //$
        background-color: blue;  //onle need this line
    }

        .button:hover {
            background-color: darkkhaki;
        }


</style>
</head>
<body>
<div style=" width: 380px; height:530px; margin: 10px auto; border:     05px solid blue; background-color: black;">
    <p1 align="right"><strong>Casio</strong></p1>
    <!--monitor-->
    <div id="monitor"><p2>0</p2></div>
    <!--buttons-->
    <div class="button">1</div>
    <div class="button">2</div>
    <div class="button">3</div>
    <div class="button">+</div>
    <div class="button">4</div>
    <div class="button">5</div>
    <div class="button">6</div>
    <div class="button">-</div>
    <div class="button">7</div>
    <div class="button">8</div>
    <div class="button">9</div>
    <div class="button">X</div>
    <div class="button">.</div>
    <div class="button">0</div>
    <div class="button">=</div>
    <div class="button">%</div>
        <div class="Dbutton">DEL</div>
        <div class="Dbutton">CLR</div>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join common settings in css:

```
.button,
.Dbutton {
    float: left;
    width: 12%;
    height: 8%;
    border: 2px solid silver;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    color: white;
    padding-left: 5%;
    position: relative;
    left: 35px;
    top: 30px;
}
.Dbutton {
    background-color: blue;  //onle need this line
}
```

Comment: Your code is working, but it disabled the hover code!

Comment: button:hover {
            background-color: darkkhaki;  // I need it for all buttons......
        }

Comment: just add same behavior: .button:hover, .Dbutton:hover  {
                    background-color: darkkhaki;
                }

Comment: Yet, your hover code works on the 2 blue buttons only. I need it for all buttons....

Comment: You forgot a dot before "button". That's all.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like this...

`<div class="button Dbutton">DEL</div>`

`<div class="button Dbutton">CLR</div>`

And Dbutton will becomes...

```
.Dbutton { 
    background-color: blue;  //onle need this line 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Please Read the comments in css. I hope this will help you.**

```
         <!DOCTYPE html>
          <html>
          <head>
          <title>Lab 1 example</title>
          <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <style>

            body {
                font-family: Verdana, Ariel;
                margin: 140px;
            }
            p1 {
                color: white;
                font-size: 30px;
                position: relative;
                left: 15px;
                top: 00px;
                padding-left: 2%;
                margin-top: 1%;
            }

            p2 {
                color: black;
                font-size: 30px;
                padding-right: 1%;
                padding-bottom: 2%;
                position: relative;
                top: 60px;
            }


            #monitor {
                background-color: lightgreen;
                color: black;
                font-size: 30px;
                border: 3px solid red;
                width: 90%;
                height: 20%;
                padding-right: 3%;
                margin: auto;
                position: relative;
                left: 01px;
                top: 10px;
                text-align: right;

            }

            .button {
                float: left;
                width: 12%;
                height: 8%;
                border: 2px solid silver;
                cursor: pointer;
                text-align: center;
                padding: 10px;
                color: white;
                padding-left: 5%;
                position: relative;
                left: 35px;
                top: 30px;
            }
        .button:nth-child(n+19){
        background-color: blue;
        }

            /*Just use this selector which selects a specific range of childs 
             OR 
      .button:nth-last-child(-n+3){
        background-color: blue;
        }
            */
                .button:hover {
                    background-color: darkkhaki;
                }


        </style>
        </head>
        <body>
        <div style=" width: 380px; height:530px; margin: 10px auto; border:     05px solid blue; background-color: black;">
            <p1 align="right"><strong>Casio</strong></p1>
            <!--monitor-->
            <div id="monitor"><p2>0</p2></div>
            <!--buttons-->
            <div class="button">1</div>
            <div class="button">2</div>
            <div class="button">3</div>
            <div class="button">+</div>
            <div class="button">4</div>
            <div class="button">5</div>
            <div class="button">6</div>
            <div class="button">-</div>
            <div class="button">7</div>
            <div class="button">8</div>
            <div class="button">9</div>
            <div class="button">X</div>
            <div class="button">.</div>
            <div class="button">0</div>
            <div class="button">=</div>
            <div class="button">%</div>
                <div class="button">DEL</div>
                <div class="button">CLR</div>
            <div style="clear:both"></div>

        </div>

        </body>
        </html>`enter code here`
```